# How do I Get Individual Objects from JsonArray using Retrofit?

Tags: android, arrays, json, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm trying to use Retrofit to get an array from my API. I then need to grab certain objects from the array to use in different parts of my app. Using the below code, I can get a Successful response, but when I try to log the response I get this...

```
myapp.com.myapp.LocationsModel@9a0d130
```

I need the actual array to be returned so I can grab objects (Strings) from the array. I ave tried several different implementations from Google and Stack Overflow, and I can't get this to work for the life of me. Maybe I'm overlooking something simple. This is my first time using Retrofit instead of Volley. Thanks for any help. Here is my model from LocationsModel. I have also pasted the api response that I'm trying to receive and parse.

**Model**

```
@GET("locations")
    Call<List<LocationsModel>> getLocations(@Header("authorization") String token);
```

**Client**

```
public void getContests() {
       // SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String token = LoginActivity.authToken;
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Interface.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        Interface api = retrofit.create(Interface.class);
            Log.v("sendtoken", token);

        Call<List<LocationsModel>> call = api.getLocations(token);



        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<LocationsModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<LocationsModel>> call, Response<List<LocationsModel>> response) {
                int statusCode = response.code();
                Log.d("Response Code", "Response Code: " + statusCode);
                Log.d("LocArray", "arr: " + Arrays.toString(response.body().toArray()));

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<LocationsModel>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("response-failure", call.toString());
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
```

**API Json Array Response**

```
[
    {
        "how_it_works": [
            "Test program"
        ],
        "id": 242,
        "business_id": 162,
        "title": "Take 10% off",
        "desc_short": "10% off",
        "logo_url": "http://www.logourl.com",
        "hashtag": "#Octo",
        "confirm_message_title": "Confirm Message",
        "rules": "
The rules

",
        "confirm_message": "Confirmation",
        "start_date": "2018-04-01T05:00:00.000Z",
        "end_date": "2018-06-01T04:59:59.000Z",
        "active": true,
        "entry_count": 0,
        "created_at": "2018-04-16T19:15:03.000Z",
        "updated_at": "2018-04-16T19:15:57.000Z",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "locations": [
            {
                "id": 232,
                "business_id": 162,
                "name": "Trent Home",
                "address": "123 Second Place",
                "city": "Rochester",
                "state": "OK",
                "zipcode": "35854",
                "latitude": 33.0785,
                "longitude": -87.5819,
                "radius": 280.14,
                "created_at": "2018-04-16T19:15:40.000Z",
                "updated_at": "2018-04-16T19:15:40.000Z",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "contest_locations": {
                    "created_at": "2018-04-16T19:15:48.000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2018-04-16T19:15:48.000Z",
                    "contest_id": 242,
                    "location_id": 232
                },
                "stickers": [
                    "http://www.stickerurl.com"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "entries": []
    },
    {
        "how_it_works": [
            "Take a photo, get a reward"
        ],
        "id": 292,
        "business_id": 162,
        "title": "Take 15% off",
        "desc_short": "15% off $10",
        "logo_url": "https://www.logourl.com",
        "hashtag": "#testAndroid",
        "confirm_message_title": "15% off now",
        "rules": "
rules here

",
        "confirm_message": "Complete good job",
        "start_date": "2018-04-09T05:00:00.000Z",
        "end_date": "2018-05-29T04:59:59.000Z",
        "active": true,
        "entry_count": 0,
        "created_at": "2018-04-23T16:44:42.000Z",
        "updated_at": "2018-04-23T16:44:56.000Z",
        "deleted_at": null,
        "locations": [
            {
                "id": 232,
                "business_id": 162,
                "name": "Trent Home",
                "address": "123 Main St",
                "city": "Tuls",
                "state": "Ny",
                "zipcode": "35235",
                "latitude": 33.0785,
                "longitude": -87.5819,
                "radius": 280.14,
                "created_at": "2018-04-16T19:15:40.000Z",
                "updated_at": "2018-04-16T19:15:40.000Z",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "contest_locations": {
                    "created_at": "2018-04-23T16:44:49.000Z",
                    "updated_at": "2018-04-23T16:44:49.000Z",
                    "contest_id": 292,
                    "location_id": 232
                },
                "stickers": []
            }
        ],
        "entries": []
    }
]
```

Comment: Override `toString` method in your `LocationsModel` class and it'll display nicer

Comment: It looks like it's working, you are getting a List<LocationsModel>. Try `Log.d("First location: ", response.body().get(0).getTitle());`

Comment: @LeoPelozo Wow, I'm a little embarrassed, but youre right. I was forgetting to give it an index number to pull from when asking it to get(). Thanks so much!

Comment: You are welcome :)